# Tor Error Log - non-control connections-any solution

Tags: error, log

i recently came up with this message when tried to run tor while vpn was running as well.

OS- osx 
any clues if this has to do with man-in-the-middle attack or not?
see pic for log[image]

Answer (score 1):

The log you're showing can be MitM - and there's how to check it:

- make a `su` to your Tor user
- do a traceroute to the 109.105.109.147 - or also to other IP's that are mentioned in that `Problem bootstrapping` messages.

If the trace(s) completes OK - then it is a MitM proven. If it's not - do `netstat -r` and examine your routing table: many VPN's are setting itself as a default router, so it can be either a "route table switch" moment, but it should repair itself in time, or you may have a routing issue. Yes, some VPN's - especially in Russia - did the MitM attempt when using Tor through them when it was not violating their ToS. So the outcome of your test will show the truth.

Comment: hm, can you write an example of the commands with pathnames to understand what i have to do. thanks

Comment: in a terminal do `traceroute 109.105.109.147` and copy and paste it's output. If you have had any other IP's which were referred in error messages like `[WARN] Problem bootstrapping ....` like on your screenshot - do this command run for them as well and paste the output too

Comment: i did the traceroute, thanks. in the output, from number / line  11 and after, shows 4 stars (****) and continues infinitely. I pressed control-break and stopped it. not sure if i have to let it go more time. in the WARN there was no other ip's listed. shall i run it again or the asterisks show it did not complete ?

Comment: yes - let it complete. It usually does 32 steps

Comment: ok, thanks !  I did that and goes over 45 steps 14-45 all are asterisks.
I noticed that the output results at beginning were different from the last time if i remember ok. i stopped it again.

it seems it does not stop.

i noticed also that my firewall stats for openvpn shows incoming and outgoing connection. is that normal ?

Today utorrent asked me for an incoming connection, although they were hundreds coming in and no forewall notification popups until that ip.

Comment: You seem to need a pluggable transports, and bridges... If traces are dying like that it means censorship at work on your connection. Try meek and obfs3 and obfs4, it should help

Comment: in your case it seems to be an active MitM with access blocking by IP. About your firewall message about no servers - can you describe the situation and the message itself in more details so I can take a closer look?

Comment: openvpn client was unable to connect to your vpn provider servers?

Comment: yes i believe. true. dont know if open vpn does other jobs as well

Comment: how do i fix the mitm problem... this is serious

Comment: then you have an access filtering for sure: I worked at ISP's and at service providers for years and there's always a simple failover schema for VPN too: if you have 3 servers, for example, they are never going down simultaniously - one rebooting, two are working, so clients are able to have the service provided. I don't see any hazard of IP leaking or exposing if you just was unable to connect to VPN

Comment: yes, MitM is a very serious by itself, and if the access filtering is in order - it makes it worse. We can chat in skype by the way - my facebook profile is in my profile here. Add me and I'll send you my skype - let's fix this! what do you think?

Comment: go to my facebook profile https://www.facebook.com/avesnin and press "add friend" - or send your profile link. there's no profile messaging in SE network, sadly

Comment: i wonder who that bloke is ehehe

Comment: added you - add me in skype and let's fix it!